# it is possible to migrate J2EE Applications to a cloud-based services?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cloud, saas

Does anyone know how much effort, time and budget (and even if it's posible) is required to change traditional J2EE application development to "on-the-cloud" services, I mean databases, datasources, security concerns, etc.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, certainly YES!!! Depending on the architecture of your application you may choose from the following solutions (my suggestions):

IAAS: [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine), etc.
PASS: [Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com), [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/java-paas), [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com), [Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), etc.

**Effort and Time**
I would say the effort required is minimal, almost as equal to a local setup for IAAS and even easier with PAAS.

**Budget**
These services are also relatively cheap, check out their pricing info.

**Databases/Datasources**
Easily configurable.

**Security Concerns**
Should be same as the ones applicable if you had locally hosted.

You may wish to have a look at a recent **[guide](http://www.dzone.com/page/2013-guide-paas-and-iaas)** published by DZONE

Comment: For Amazon, you can go IAAS or PAAS (using http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)

Comment: @user2264997 will add it to the list. The ones I had mentioned are the ones I personally have used.